# Помогите выявить ошибку и правильно прописать маршруты

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Итак, есть `Oracle VM VirtualBox`. В нём утановлены 2 виртуальные машины:
`Win XP` c двумя сетевыми адаптерами:

1. `Host-only Adapter`. Name: `vboxnet0`
2. `Internal Network`. Name: `my lan`

В `win xp` настроены следующие подключения по локальной сети:
`Host-only Adapter` - 192.168.1.1/24
`Internal Network` - 192.168.2.1/24

`Win Server 2003` с одним сетевым адаптером:

1. `Internal Network`. Name: `my lan`

В `win server` настроено подключение на `Internal Network` - 192.168.2.10/24. Default Gateway: 192.168.2.1

Всё это запущено на физической машине с Linux Mint.
Эта физическая машина в сети `vboxnet0` имеет следующие настройки:

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:69301 (69.3 KB)
```

Задача состоит в том, что бы настроить маршрутизацию на компьютере с `Windows Xp`.
На машине с `Win Xp` я прописываю следующие маршруты:

```
route add 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

Вот так выглядит результат команды `route` на виртуальной машине с `win xp`.
[image: route-table]

На физической машине я прописываю следующий маршрут:

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.0
```

Вот так выглядит результат команды `route` на физической машине:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         dir-300         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2ca568140112
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.2.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 vboxnet0
```

Проблема в том, что с физической машины адреса 192.168.2.1 и 192.168.1.1 пингуются, но адрес 192.168.2.10 нет :(

Comment: Зачем добавлять роуты класса connected, еслиони и так добавляются при задании адреса и маски

Comment: @eri Спасибо вам большое за ответ, он помог решить проблему! Но не могли бы вы пояснить подробнее ваш коментарий. Если честно я совсем не понял о чём вы :)

Comment: Эти два маршрута уже есть, их добавлять не нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб заработала маршрутизация через ХР нужно на ней запустить службу маршрутизация и удаленный доступ. На интерфейсе откуда идут подключения нужно поставить галочку "разрешить совместное использование" на последней вкладке.